# Goal conversion not registering when using event value condition equals 0

Tags: google-analytics

I am tracking events with category of "Outbound" and value set to either 0 or positive integer. I am using the same code to track the event, regardless of the value, and have confirmed that when the value is set to 0, that is what the GA code is submitting, and that the value is not null.

When defining an Event type goal with Value "Greater than" 0, the goals are being properly measured.  When defining an Event type goal with Value "Equals to" 0, no goals are being counted, both with the Verify command, real-time conversion data and after several days of confirmed events with Category of "Outbound" and Value of 0 (not null) that should meet this criteria.

Below is a link to a screenshot of the goal details.  Can anyone shed some light on why this might be happening?

[Goal Definition with Value Condition of Equals to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdKBF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you are using Google Tag Manager. Are you ?

Eventually try 'label = {{Click URL}}' and leave value blank

The event should specify what the 'Click URL' conditions are (in your case -> greater than 0). But what do you want to measure ? If it's outbound link clicks, specify 'Click URL' does not contain 'your_site.com'

Comment: I'm using Analytics.js. The event I am capturing is a click on a button that does some processing, sends the event to GA, and then redirects the user.  I need to use value to capture a quantity associated with the clicked element.  I'm trying to separate the conversions triggered by this click into 2 goals, based on whether the value is zero or greater than zero. I am already using category, action, and label so I can't redeploy one of those properties to use to differentiate into the 2 goals.

Comment: Upon examination of the request sent when sending an event back to GA, it appears that when the event value is zero, the ev parameter which is normally sent when there is an event value is not included at all, so you cannot record an event with value explicitly set to zero. I submitted an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74222253) to Google about this.